Converting differential calculus problem to variational calculus problem
I was reading The Finite Element Method for Engineers by Huebner, and read that solving for $\phi$ in the following differential equation
$\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}=-f(x)$, $\phi(a)=A$, $\phi(b)=B$
is equivalent to seeking the function $\phi(x)$ that minimizes the following functional
$J(\phi)=\int_a^b[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x})^2-f(x)\phi(x)]dx$
I think there should be a plus sign in the functional:
$J(\phi)=\int_a^b[\frac{1}{2}(\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x})^2+f(x)\phi(x)]dx$
Am I wrong? If yes, could you please explain how to get from the differential equation to the functional form?

do you know about the Euler-Lagrange equation for functionals of this kind?

I'm not sure how they got the integrand...

The Euler-Lagrange Equation states that the function $\mathcal{L}$ minimizing the functional
$S[\mathcal{L}] = \displaystyle \int_a^b \mathcal{L}(\phi,\dot{\phi},x) dx$, where $\displaystyle \dot{\phi} = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$.
obeys the following equation:
$\displaystyle \dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}$.
The second-order differential equation you gave is equivalent to solving for the motion of a particle under a conservative force. We know that for such a motion, the Lagrangian can be written as $\mathcal{L} = T-U = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{\phi}^2 - U(\phi)$.
Then, let's try to draw parallels between the equation:
$\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} = \dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}$ and $\displaystyle -f(x) = \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}$.
In the most straightforward way, we might equate $\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi} = -f(x)$ and $\dfrac{d}{dx}\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}} = \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}$, which is equivalent to $\dfrac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}} = \dfrac{d\phi}{dx} = \dot{\phi}$.
See that the following Lagrangian satisfies both equations:
$\mathcal{L} = \dfrac{1}{2}\dot{\phi}^2 - \phi(x)f(x)$, which also fits the form $\mathcal{L} = T-U$, which supports our intuition.
Then, the differential equation $\displaystyle -f(x) = \dfrac{d^2\phi}{dx^2}$ is indeed equivalent to minimizing the functional
$J(\phi) = \displaystyle \int_a^b \big[\dfrac{1}{2}\big(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}\big)^2 - \phi(x)f(x) \big] dx$
